# Creating form in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL database wich containes a table with type point an 4  tables without geometry.

[image]

I created foreign keys to garantee the relations between those tables. I migrated my db via postgis to QGIS. I made the the relations in QGIS once again.

[image]

After that I created a form where I wanted to add a relation in a tab.

[image]
 when I edit the feature where i added the relation I can see the fields in the tab.
[image]

Yet when I consult it from the attribute table when moving to form view I can't find it and when I creat a package to QField I also don't see it

[image]
[image]

if you have any idea about why I can't see my tab tell me.